# How can I get vpython results to show inline in jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, vpython

Jupyterlab hangs and does not display the results of evaluation when I try to run any graphical vpython code, eg...

```
from vpython import *
canvas()
box(vector-(0,0,0))
```

I have tried this in both colab notebooks and in my local jupyter setup built using anaconda. The plots work fine when working in spyder.

I tried running the notebook in chromium, firefox, and librewolf without any change. In the environment I am running python=3.8, jupyterlab=4.0.5, and notebook=7.0.3 using on a machine running archlinux.

Comment: Which example is your code based on? Have you tried running exactly what you provided in that code block yourself? You say Spyder works for you; however, did you try that example with Spyder? When I run it, I see `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'type' and 'tuple'` in regards to the line `box(vector-(0,0,0))`. So it seems like a bad example to expect to work. There are `.ipynb` example files [here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter/tree/master/Demos).

Comment: By the way if you need an example in Jupyter where this works, go [here](https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter#sample-program) and click `'launch binder` at the bottom of that section. (Now be aware this is a little convoluted of a way to activate things and it still doesn't result in it working in JupyterLab, but it at least allows it to work in the older version of Jupyter Notebook served via MyBinder.) When the session starts up, click the 'Plot3D' example about 2/3 down the list of available notebooks. Then right-click on the Jupyter logo in the upper left and copy the link. ...

Comment: <continued> Close the Plot3D browser window for now. Paste that link you copied in a new browser window and then JupyterLab will open. When that shows JupyterLab, double click on the 'Demos' directory in the file browser list on the left. Next, right click on `Plot3D.ipynb` in the file browser list on the left and shut down the kernel. Then Double-click on `Plot3D.ipynb` in the list and then run the top cell there when the file opens. Give it a minute or two to try to render things. (It will make some space below the first cell but in my experience it didn't show the output expected there.)...

Comment: <continued>  Then close the `Plot3D.ipynb` file, discarding your changes, and even close the browser window where JupyterLab is open. Now go back to the Jupyter Notebook window that first opened after you launched the session. And remove the `notebooks/index.ipynb` at the end of the URL and replace it with `tree`. That will open the Jupyter Notebook Jupyter Dashboard. Double click to go into the 'Demos' directory in the classic Jupyter Notebook interface. Click on the square to the left of the green `Plot3D.ipynb` in the list and then go up and press the 'ShutDown' button at the top of the ...

Comment: <continued> listing. Then scroll down, give it a moment to fully shutdown that kernel, and then double click `Plot3D.ipynb` in the list so that it opens in the classic interface and then run the top cell in the notebook that just opened. It should hang and not show the plot still in my experience just now. Go up to the menu above the notebook and from under 'Kernel', click 'Restart & Run All'. Be patient and give it about a minute. It may indeed now show the plot and you should be able to click on other notebooks back in the Dashboard ...

Comment: <continued> and they will now run and display the VPython output. However if that doesn't work quite yet continue on try this ... Close that notebook window and then again click on the square to the left of the green `Plot3D.ipynb` in the list and then go up and press the 'ShutDown' button at the top of the listing. Then scroll down and double click `Stars.ipynb` in the list so that it opens in the classic interface and then run the top cell in the notebook that just opened. Let it run, ...

Comment: <continued> it may take about a minute but it should run and show the VPython canvas. Once that works, you should be able to open other Demo `.ipynb` files, even the `Plot3D.ipynb` one. I know it seems weird and convoluted but that consistently works right now to get VPython running in the classic notebook interface served via MyBinder. I think you have to try JupyterLab first because running something there triggers something or some setting on the server that is needed. ...

Comment: <continued> I couldn't tell you why, or why you need to shutdown the kernel twice & do restart in the classic interface or possibly even try another `.ipynb` file, but this at least currently works to get VPython running in Jupyter in some manner without needing to touch your own system. I couldn't get VPython to work in the classic notebook interface to work without first trying JupyterLab interface. Even after working in the classic interface, I'm not seeing it work in JupyterLab there.